# Parse yaml with keys provide errors

Tags: go, yaml

I’ve the following yaml which I need to parse,
I’ve tried with the following

```
Build-t:
  before: test1
    - value : dddd 
       -  bbb: zzzz

  after: test2
     - value: bbb
        - aaa: aaaa
```

I’ve tried with the following:

```
type root struct{
 build type Build `yaml:"Build-t,omitempty"`
} 


type Build struct {
    Before map[string]interface{} `yaml:"before,omitempty"`
    After map[string]interface{} `yaml:"after,omitempty"`
 }
```

Now when I parse it I got error,

What I need is to get the values from the object `before` and `after` which are hardcoded value in the yaml
And all the others value under it are dynmically can be added therefor I put it as `interface`

btw, if I change the root to this its working and I see all the fields under the `Build-t` but the `before and after` are like keys ...

```
type root struct{
 build type map[string]interface{} `yaml:"Build-t,omitempty"`
}
```

the error is:

```
line 6: cannot unmarshal !!str `test1` into map[string]interface {}
        line 7: cannot unmarshal !!str `test2` into map[string]interface {}
```

see the yaml valid here
https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cb705458

Comment: What do you mean by "I got error" - is there any error message given that you could share?

Comment: @NicoHaase - sure, please see my update

Comment: Your YAML example does not look like valid YAML in the first place.

Comment: @Iguananaut - please see my update

Comment: The `build` field of your `root` struct is unexported and cannot be unmarshaled into.

Comment: @NinaS I'm not sure that YAML validator looks correct.  I've spent a lot of time with YAML and I've never seen anything like what you wrote, though I could be wrong. But it's really unclear what your data structure is intended to be here.  `before: test1` indicates a map with key `before` and value of the string `test1`.  Then under that you start a new data structure (an omap maybe) but it's not clear what parent structure it belongs to.

Comment: Don't ever use the "validator" at codebeautify.com, it accepts some invalid YAML, and reject some perfectly fine YAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds correct - the YAML is invalid. Did you mean something like this?

```
Build-t:
 before:
   test1:
     - value: dddd
     - bbb: zzzz

 after:
   test2:
     - value: bbb
     - aaa: aaaa
```

Remember that the whitespace is important, and it's a key-value structure - so your values can either be strings, or substructures - not both.

Also, that yaml validator... I can't seem to make it declare anything as invalid!